# Alternative to Android Cruton

Tags: android, view, notifications

In our app we want to enable in app notifications, like this one:[image: custom notification].

We're looking for open source solutions and have found [cruton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) which looks like a good fit but was last updated over two years ago. 
We also looked at snackbars, but this view only disappears when the user has clicked the x sign so it's not a classic snackbar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Snackbar` supports `LENGTH_INDEFINITE`, for manual dismissal.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good alternative with this [library](https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar)